# Which type of cluster analysis to perform?

Tags: clustering, heterogeneity, model-based-clustering

I am trying to explain variability in the outcome, and understand factors that may be associated with different clusters? I am confused as to which clustering method to use to obtain 3 clusters as circled below after running a linear regression between physical inactivity and BMI? Once I have the 3 groups of individuals in clusters (Group 1 = low physical inactivity and high BMI ; Group 2 = good prediction; Group 3 = high physical inactivity and low BMI), then I plan to examine factors such as age or sex that may associated with these clusters (i.e., explain why these clusters are different).

[image: Scatter Plot]

Comment: Do I get it right that you _don't_ have the regression line shown for now, because you haven't done the clustering yet?

Comment: @ttnphns; I do have the regression line. So what I am trying to do is explain why certain people have lower physical inactivity and higher BMI (because we should not expect this). I am wondering if there is any way to use cluster analysis to create 3 clusters (people who's BMI was overestimated, good prediction, and underestimated). I am not sure how to do this? Then after this, I will examine factors that may explain differences in clusters, for example, groups of people who are under or overpredicted good may be older in age than those who had good prediction.

Comment: But it looks from the pic that you've fitted the prediction line on the oblong cluster only, and not on the complete data, right? So, it comes you already know the oblong cluster, isn't it?

Comment: @ttnphns; That's correct. So, now what I want to know is that is it possible to do some sort of cluster analysis using an exposure (physical inactivity) and outcome (BMI) variable and have individuals grouped into clusters: 1) people with poor prediction (greater distance between observed score vs prediction line) and 2) those who have a good prediction (closer distance between observed score vs prediction line).

Comment: Also, even though I have already fitted the prediction line, I can start from the beginning but the idea is that I want to create clusters (not manually) based on how well they are predicted.

Comment: Trusting your concrete picture, one could suggest simply to do cluster analysis of the residuals (i.e, single variable). There will be three quite clear clusters. As they are clear and the situation is 1D,  almost any method of clustering, including hierarchical or k-means, might work.

Comment: @ttnphns; So I got the residual values. I am not sure if I can perform cluster analysis on this and whether that would be the correct procedure. I think I need to perform some sort of latent analysis which will group the residual into 3 and then examine the influence of each of the covariates such as age and sex on each of the 3 groups of residuals.